# How would I pass a virtual method through an abstract class but optionally not override?

Tags: c++, methods, overriding, virtual

I'm trying to pass a virtual method through an abstract class, but to only have some of it's derived classes override the base method, with the others running the original method.

```c
class Animal {
    virtual void speak() {
         //generic speaking code
    }
}
class Mammal : Animal {
    virtual void speak() = 0;
    //allows speak to be overridden by derived class
}
class Dog : Mammal {
    //doesn't do anything special with speak(), should run generic speaking code
}
class Human : Mammal {
    void speak() {
        //overrides generic speaking code
    }
}
```

I'd like calling speak() from Dog to run Animal's speak() method, but calling speak() from Human to run it's own speak() method. How would I go about this?

Comment: Btw, I missed the mistake in your code of not using public inheritance. I updated my answer just now.

Comment: Was your use of **private** inheritance voluntary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need this in `Mammal`:

```
virtual void speak() = 0;
```

`Human` can still override `speak()` just fine, and `Dog` doesn't have to. Make sure you're using public inheritance though, not private inheritance. That is:

```
class Mammal : public Animal {
```

instead of:

```
class Mammal : Animal {
```

As a side-note, you should be using the `override` keyword when overriding virtual functions. It helps catch the somewhat common error of thinking you're overriding a function while in fact you're just overloading it. So your code should be:

```
class Animal {
public:
    virtual void speak()
    {}
};

class Mammal : public Animal {
};

class Dog : public Mammal {
};

class Human : public Mammal {
public:
    void speak() override
    {}
};
```